# Directshow Render window DLL,

Tags: dll, window, directshow, renderer

Is there a way to pop up the directshow render windows from DLL.
Same code pops up the video render window from .exe application.
DLLs are libraries so you can not have a graphical sort of feed back I suppose. 
Well I know it is a reciepe for a disaster, but it is just for debugging.

I came across this.

[How to show a simple modeless Window from a native C DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833250/how-to-show-a-simple-modeless-window-from-a-native-c-dll)

Would any of the suggestions work ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No constraints exist that prevent you from interacting with DirectShow API from DLL. You can do all the same GUI from there. Moreover, no hacks involved - you do it in a straightforward way: you create window, you create DirectShow graph and filters, you set everything up and it works the same way.

Comment: This is my set up.
Have a .NET /C# project, which calls my unmanaged stuff which is a in dll. If I run the same snippet in an .exe the code works and it does show the rendering window. 
Interesting thing is when I change my renderer( to one I wrote which does not render but just consumes the data and does nothing. Like a sample grabber). The data passes through the filters. But then I put the renderer,  the flow stops(blocks) at the first receive function of the IMEMPin. So I was thinking the data is not flowing because there is no render window because the code is in a dll.

Comment: There have to be a reason why it does not work in your DLL, however it is not because of "DLL" and rather because "your". Because something is wrong there.